# What is the return type of this pointer?

Tags: c++

As declaration of this pointer is as under

**Datatype * const this**

Here what will be the return datatype ?

what does it mean?

Comment: Well, a pointer does not have a return type, for it's a pointer, and not a function -- a pointer itself does not `return` anything. You may be trying to ask something else your words were not able to properly express. Please, try to improve your question, making clearer what you want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointers do not have *"return types"* - they're types not functions. The declaration in your question means that `this` points to an instance of `Datatype`. The `const` qualifier on the right hand side of `*` means that the value of `this` cannot be changed. Since there is no `const` qualifier on the left side of `*` the object `this` pointers to *can* be changed. `this` is a reserved word in C++ that acts like a pointer and can only be used inside of non-static member functions. It points to the current object for which a non-static member function is being executed on. `this` *cannot* be explicitly declared

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a keyword in C++ and can't be used as a user-declared symbol.  But assuming:

```
Datatype * const this;
```

declares `this` as a user declaration would, it's type would be a `const` pointer to type `Datatype`.